# How do I let the module know where the external library is located?

Tags: 8

On a fresh installation of Drupal 8, I installed a third-party module that requires an external library. I uploaded the library to the site.

How do I let the module know where the external library is located?

Comment: Generally, modules need to be installed with Composer, which will handle the installation of the libraries for you. That said, sometimes modules do it differently. See if you can find documentation on the download page, or a README in the module folder for installation instructions.

Comment: What module did you install and how did you install it?

Comment: International Phone is the module in question.  I don't have a test system set up on my PC and I don't want to go that way.  The server is my test system.  Therefore, Composer is out of the question.  That said, surely there must be a manual way to point to the desired file location.

Comment: Composer is not listed as a requirement of Drupal 8, but it's essentially required. I've never seen anyone who has been able to put together a proper tutorial on how to use D8 without Composer. See this person's comments: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2020-05-18/installing-drupal-8-with-or-without-composer#comment-13620817

Answer (score 1):

The [International Phone](https://www.drupal.org/project/phone_international) module's page says that Composer is required to install the module. The module doesn't have a setting page where you can say where the library has been copied, and that is expected, from a module that requires Composer.

Composer is not a tool you normally use on a production server, and using the production server as test server is pretty wrong.

When I have to install Drupal on a shared hosting that doesn't allow me to use SSH, I install Composer on the local computer, I use a Composer template to copy  Drupal in a directory and I add the modules I need with `composer require`. I can then use that directory for a local site where I can verify that adding a module, or updating the site, doesn't cause issues.

When a module requires Composer, there aren't other ways to let it know where the libraries from which it depends have been installed.
They are loaded from the *autoload.php* file created from Composer. You could manually create that file, but that would be a bad idea, especially because that file is created basing on some settings present in the *composer.json* file that comes with Drupal core.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was told by several individuals that a server was not the place to develop Drupal apps.  While clutching their pearls in horror, what they didn't understand is that the server is not a production server, but simply a space I rent on a server to experiment with Drupal.

However, as I have now spent two months reading, studying, and experimenting, I see that Drupal development really has to be done on a PC or similar and then uploaded.  It is unfortunate that a server-based system cannot be developed on a server.  But it is what it is.

I have therefore made the decision to stop trying to make Drupal work for me.  Instead, I am going with HTML5 and JQuery and build my own system.  After two months of this, I probably could have already had a working system.

Comment: Yeah, Drupal has a steep learning curve. Generally, you need to build a few sites first to learn how it works, before you can branch out and start building creative sites that do new things.